# Trying to use a UUID for a primary key. Getting stale data on SQLalchemy commit()

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, primary-key, uuid, staledataexception

Starting SQLalchemy user here. I plan to use UUID's as the primary keys for my tables.

In the tutorial I saw some code for using the native Python UUID type in ORM classes. Eureka! I can use Postgresql's native UUID type for my system database and this TypeDecorator will stringify the UUID's for SQLite on my mobile clients.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/types.html#backend-agnostic-guid-type

Sadness. When using this with an **existing** SQLite database that has stringified UUID's as the primary key I get stale data errors when I try to commit any changes.

This class crashes with stale data on commit.

```
class CommodityTypes(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'CommodityTypes'
    uuidKey = Column(GUID, primary_key=True)
    myName = Column(String, unique = True)
    sortKey = Column(Integer, unique = True)
```

, but this class works:

```
class NewTypes(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'CommodityTypes'
    uuidKey = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    myName = Column(String, unique = True)
    sortKey = Column(Integer, unique = True)
```

Queried objects from the CommodityTypes class show the python UUID type for uuidKey. The script queries the object correctly. I can change settings, but I can't commit. The decorated uuidKey doesn't seem to work.

I can go forward just using Strings for the uuidKey columns, but it frustrates me that the code from http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/types.html#backend-agnostic-guid-type **almost** works.

Here's sample code with the problem. The string workaround not using the GUID type decorator is commented out.

```
#system modules
import uuid

#other modules
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator, CHAR
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
from sqlalchemy.orm.exc import MultipleResultsFound, NoResultFound

engine = create_engine('sqlite:////home/XXXX/XobfuscatedXXXX/XXXXXXXX.sqlite')

Base = declarative_base()

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

class GUID(TypeDecorator):
    """Platform-independent GUID type.

    Uses Postgresql's UUID type, otherwise uses
    CHAR(32), storing as stringified hex values.

    """
    impl = CHAR

    def load_dialect_impl(self, dialect):
        if dialect.name == 'postgresql':
            return dialect.type_descriptor(UUID())
        else:
            return dialect.type_descriptor(CHAR(32))

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return value
        elif dialect.name == 'postgresql':
            return str(value)
        else:
            if not isinstance(value, uuid.UUID):
                return "%.32x" % uuid.UUID(value)
            else:
                # hexstring
                return "%.32x" % value

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return value
        else:
            return uuid.UUID(value)

from sqlalchemy import Column, Boolean, DateTime, Date, Float, ForeignKey, Integer, Numeric, String

class CommodityTypes(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'CommodityTypes'
    uuidKey = Column(GUID, primary_key=True)
    myName = Column(String, unique = True)
    sortKey = Column(Integer, unique = True)

#class NewTypes(Base):
#    __tablename__ = 'CommodityTypes'
#    uuidKey = Column(String, primary_key=True)
#    myName = Column(String, unique = True)
#    sortKey = Column(Integer, unique = True)

if __name__=="__main__":
    session = Session()
#    newList = session.query(NewTypes).order_by(NewTypes.sortKey)
#    for instance in newList:
#        print(instance.myName)
#
#    nt = newList[1]
#    print(nt.myName)
#    print(nt.sortKey)
#    nt.sortKey = 11
#    print(nt.sortKey)
#    session.commit()
#    print(nt.sortKey)

    ctList = session.query(CommodityTypes).order_by(CommodityTypes.sortKey)
    for instance in ctList:
        print(instance.myName)
    ct = ctList[1]
    print(ct.myName)
    print(ct.sortKey)
    ct.sortKey = 22
    print(ct.sortKey)
    session.commit()
    print(ct.sortKey)
```

Oh, forgot to mention software versions:

Python 3.1.3 (r313:86834, Dec  1 2010, 06:15:12)

[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)] on linux2

Comment: you'd need to provide actual sample data to reproduce the error.  something is probably not matching up with the actual data in your sqlite database.  if the GUID type works for round trips where it also creates the data, then you know the issue is with the existing data.